# Getting error when using react-pdf library with latest version

Tags: react-pdf

Getting the below error when using react-pdf 6^.2.2 version. Its working fine when i am using 4.1.0 version.
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1413:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| class PDFDocumentLoadingTask {

> static #docId = 0;
> |
> |   constructor() {

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVQyp.png)
I want to use latest version of react-pdf to show the pdf view

Comment: Some component you're using doesn't support the `#` private variable syntax. You're not telling us anything about the other components, so it's hard to help further.

Comment: We are not using "#" in our code. Its fetching from the react-pdf library for version 6.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. I meant the version of e.g. webpack, babel-loader, ... whatever you may be using, that you're not showing us.